# Setting Excel chart title programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, charts, com, interop

How to set a chart title with C# and Interop?

Actually trying:

```
            Excel.Range chartRange;

            Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlsSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
            Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

            chartRange = xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlsSheet.Cells[ar.GetLength(0), ar.GetLength(1)]];
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows);
            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn;
            chartPage.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet, oOpt);

            chartPage.HasTitle = true;
            chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "HeaderText";
```

Giving sweet

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on my own.

Just set the title before the chartPage is filled with information.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of  `chartPage.HasTitle = true;` another way is by applying some chart layout containing a Title field before setting the title. In the case of xl3DColumn Chart :

```
chartPage.ApplyLayout (1)
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "HeaderText"
```

Comment: glad you found the solution :)